# boost example failed to build

Tags: c++, macos, boost, build-process, boost-regex

I'm a newbie about boost. I compiled boost libraries with success (under mac os x). Now, I tried to build the very first example mentioned at boost website (including boost/ as include directory and boost/stage/lib as library directory, with netbeans) and got the following error

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/boost_ex1
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -I../../boost_1_44_0 -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o.d -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/boost_ex1 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o -L../../boost_1_44_0/stage/lib 
Undefined symbols:
  "boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack()in main.o
  "boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > const&)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_match()in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) constin main.o
      boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) constin main.o
  "boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::re_detail::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()", referenced from:
      bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) constin main.o
  "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) constin main.o
  "boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/boost_ex1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Most Boost libraries are header-only:
>   they consist entirely of header files
>   containing templates and inline
>   functions, and require no
>   separately-compiled library binaries
>   or special treatment when linking.

However, the [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library has a library you have to link with if you are using its code. For more details on this see [Getting Started guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#header-only-libraries).

So the problem in your case is that you are not linking with [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) library, called `libboost_regex.so`. In order to do that, modify your project settings (or make file) so that it invokes gcc with `-lboost_regex` option. This option should come right after `-L../../boost_1_44_0/stage/lib` option that you already have, like this

```
g++ -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/boost_ex1 build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main.o -L../../boost_1_44_0/stage/lib -lboost_regex
```

Good luck!

Comment: yeah thank you! I was using neatbeans, and I thought that adding the libraries directory would automatically generate -lboost_regex option.

Comment: @Banana: You are welcome. Boost has auto-link option, but that works only with Visual Studio C++ compiler on Windows. Otherwise you have to do it manually because neither NetBeans nor compiler or linker knows what exactly you need to link with.